# Array merging issue

Tags: php, array-merge

I've following two `arrays` as follows,

```
$array1 = array
    (
        'Name' => 'Scott',
        'Department' =>  'Sales',
        'Location' => 'USA',
        'Details' => array
            (
                15 => '90%', 
                16 => '75%',
                17 => '50%',
                18 => '60%',
                19 => '50%',
                20 => '45%',  
            ),
          );
$array2 = array
(
    'Action' => 'Imp',
    'Name' => 'Scott',
    'Department' => 'Sales',
    'Location' => 'Canada', 
    'Details' => array 
    (
             15 => '20%', 
             16 => '15%',
             17 => '25%',
             18 => '10%',
    ),
);
```

Result should be:

```
$result_arr = array
        (
            'Action' => 'Imp',
            'Name' => 'Scott',
            'Department' =>  'Sales',
            'Location' => 'Canada',
            'Details' => array
                (
                    15 => '20%', 
                    16 => '15%',
                    17 => '25%',
                    18 => '10%',
                    19 => '50%',
                    20 => '45%',  
                ),
              );
```

I've tried `array_merge` and `array union (+) operator` but none of them is fit for my requirement.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the merge requirement? What causes the value of 'sales' to be retained over 'Sales'? 'Canada' over 'USA'?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: its typo mistake,now I've corrected the question

Comment: You answerd the sales/Sales part, but not the USA/Canada part.

Comment: is the custom_field in the $array2 a typo as well or its a business logic that requires it to be merged into Details key?

Comment: What are you getting when you merge them? Can you show us the code you use to merge?

Comment: @FikriMarhan: its typo mistake.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: any `string key` or `numeric key` of `array2` should be replaced in `array1` if it exist in `array1` otherwise should be simply append to the `array1`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that resulting array should look like `$array2` and `$array2['Details']` should be extended with keys from `$array1['Details']`

```
$result_arr = $array2;
$result_arr['Details'] += $array1['Details'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$final= array_merge($array1,$array2);
$final['Details']= $final['Details']+$array1['Details'];
asort($final);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($final);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Location] => Canada
    [Action] => Imp
    [Department] => Sales
    [Name] => Scott
    [Details] => Array
        (
            [15] => 20%
            [16] => 15%
            [17] => 25%
            [18] => 10%
            [19] => 50%
            [20] => 45%
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

With as little info that was provided, I was able to get your result using this:

```
$array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
$array['Details'] = $array2['Details'] + $array1['Details'];
print_r($array);
```

The Result:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Scott
    [Department] => Sales
    [Location] => Canada
    [Details] => Array
        (
            [15] => 20%
            [16] => 15%
            [17] => 25%
            [18] => 10%
            [19] => 50%
            [20] => 45%
        )

    [Action] => Imp
)
```

Comment: There is no key 'custom_fields',its my typo mistake.Please check updated question,thanks.

Comment: When I use array_merge, I get your output, I don't know why you say it doesn't work?

Comment: if we use `array_merge` then `Details` array is vary with my requirement.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$array2['Details'] = array_merge($array1['Details'], $array2['Details']);
$result = $array2;
```